# CSV Export: Multiple Database Rows to Single Row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

**Hi,**

The problem: I Have an Export from a Database, however it needs to extract data from two tables. I Achieve this with an inner join.

`artikel` is the table with the basic information. It contains the id, article number, name, type and package form.

`article_content` is the table which contains the text which is part of the article, however, there are multiple languages. Every Article has a row for each language.

**The Export Code**

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=artikeldatenbank-' . date("dmyhi") . '.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT artikel.id, artikel.artikel_nummer, artikel.artikel_name, artikel.artikel_packung, artikel.artikel_cat, article_content.article_text, article_content.article_recuse, article_content.article_spec FROM artikel INNER JOIN article_content ON article_content.article_id = artikel.artikel_nummer');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
fputcsv($output, $row);
```

**What I want to Achieve**

I need every row from the `article_content` table by it's article in a single line, instead of multiple lines. Sorry for the links, but imgur doesn't let me upload these. (Don't know why)

What happens now (image): http://prntscr.com/ek86bn

What I Want (edited image): http://prntscr.com/ek87ct

What is the best way to achieve this? Is this possible on the way I do it now?

Answer (score 1):

Skip the VIEW solution, Solve it by code, my suggestion is

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$artikeID = '';
$newRow = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($artikeID != $row['id'])
    {
        if(!empty($newRow))
        {
            fputcsv($output, $newRow);
            $newRow = [];
        }
        $artikeID = $row['id'];
        $newRow = $row;
    }
    else 
    {
        $newRow['title-'.$row['id']] = $row['artikel_name'];
        $newRow['content-'.$row['id']] = $row['article_text'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ahmed This is partly a solution. Now it's 1 line, but only one row of all the language content is entered: prntscr.com/ek8eq5. The English and French translations in this case, are gone. Additionaly are articles without any language_content gone too

Comment: You are right, try to make a VIEW in your DB to contain each language content 
[Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Don't know how to correctly implement that in the Query. could you write me an example?